# "WARN: error in opening zip file:" when using AndroidStudio Kotlin REPL

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, read-eval-print-loop

Just wanted to use the Kotlin REPL inside android studio again but am flooded with a lot of warnings:

```
WARN: error in opening zip file: /home/ligi/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/5d6fdc8d75b93d961e2b646eb30a603e/transformed/material-1.2.1/AndroidManifest.xml
java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:225)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:155)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:126)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.impl.ZipHandler$1.createAccessor(ZipHandler.java:46)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.impl.ZipHandler$1.createAccessor(ZipHandler.java:39)
    at com.intellij.util.io.FileAccessorCache.createHandle(FileAccessorCache.java:61)
    at com.intellij.util.io.FileAccessorCache.get(FileAccessorCache.java:54)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.impl.ZipHandler.getCachedZipFileHandle(ZipHandler.java:84)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.impl.ZipHandler.acquireZipHandle(ZipHandler.java:131)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.impl.ZipHandlerBase.createEntriesMap(ZipHandlerBase.java:47)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.impl.ArchiveHandler.getEntriesMap(ArchiveHandler.java:183)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.impl.jar.CoreJarHandler.<init>(CoreJarHandler.java:42)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.impl.jar.CoreJarFileSystem.lambda$new$0(CoreJarFileSystem.java:33)
    at com.intellij.util.containers.ConcurrentFactoryMap$2.create(ConcurrentFactoryMap.java:181)
    at com.intellij.util.containers.ConcurrentFactoryMap.get(ConcurrentFactoryMap.java:40)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.impl.jar.CoreJarFileSystem.findFileByPath(CoreJarFileSystem.java:44)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreEnvironment.findJarRoot(KotlinCoreEnvironment.kt:384)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreEnvironment.contentRootToVirtualFile(KotlinCoreEnvironment.kt:363)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreEnvironment.access$contentRootToVirtualFile(KotlinCoreEnvironment.kt:109)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreEnvironment$3.invoke(KotlinCoreEnvironment.kt:206)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreEnvironment$3.invoke(KotlinCoreEnvironment.kt:109)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.ClasspathRootsResolver.convertClasspathRoots(ClasspathRootsResolver.kt:70)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreEnvironment.<init>(KotlinCoreEnvironment.kt:213)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreEnvironment.<init>(KotlinCoreEnvironment.kt:109)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreEnvironment$Companion.createForProduction(KotlinCoreEnvironment.kt:421)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.scripting.compiler.plugin.repl.GenericReplChecker.<init>(GenericReplChecker.kt:62)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.scripting.compiler.plugin.repl.GenericReplCompiler.<init>(GenericReplCompiler.kt:42)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.scripting.compiler.plugin.repl.ReplInterpreter$scriptCompiler$2.invoke(ReplInterpreter.kt:80)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.scripting.compiler.plugin.repl.ReplInterpreter$scriptCompiler$2.invoke(ReplInterpreter.kt:24)
    at kotlin.SynchronizedLazyImpl.getValue(LazyJVM.kt:74)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.scripting.compiler.plugin.repl.ReplInterpreter.getScriptCompiler(ReplInterpreter.kt)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.scripting.compiler.plugin.repl.ReplInterpreter.access$getScriptCompiler$p(ReplInterpreter.kt:24)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.scripting.compiler.plugin.repl.ReplInterpreter$scriptEvaluator$2.invoke(ReplInterpreter.kt:88)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.scripting.compiler.plugin.repl.ReplInterpreter$scriptEvaluator$2.invoke(ReplInterpreter.kt:24)
    at kotlin.SynchronizedLazyImpl.getValue(LazyJVM.kt:74)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.scripting.compiler.plugin.repl.ReplInterpreter.getScriptEvaluator(ReplInterpreter.kt)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.scripting.compiler.plugin.repl.ReplInterpreter.eval(ReplInterpreter.kt:97)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.scripting.compiler.plugin.repl.ReplFromTerminal.eval(ReplFromTerminal.kt:103)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.scripting.compiler.plugin.repl.ReplFromTerminal.one(ReplFromTerminal.kt:94)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.scripting.compiler.plugin.repl.ReplFromTerminal.doRun(ReplFromTerminal.kt:59)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.scripting.compiler.plugin.repl.ReplFromTerminal.access$doRun(ReplFromTerminal.kt:26)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.scripting.compiler.plugin.repl.ReplFromTerminal$Companion.run(ReplFromTerminal.kt:159)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.scripting.compiler.plugin.JvmCliReplShellExtension.run(JvmCliReplShellExtension.kt:24)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:109)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:52)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:88)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:44)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:98)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:76)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:45)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool$Companion.doMainNoExit(CLITool.kt:227)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool$Companion.doMainNoExit$default(CLITool.kt:225)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool$Companion.doMain(CLITool.kt:214)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler$Companion.main(K2JVMCompiler.kt:271)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.main(K2JVMCompiler.kt)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.CommandLineWrapper.main(CommandLineWrapper.java:64)
```

basically one warning per library I use - so using the REPL is not much fun and a lot of scrolling

Comment: If you could kindly provide the code you typed into the REPL? Or does that just happen when you just open the REPL in Android Studio?

Comment: The code does not really matter -happens with whatever I type in there (e.g. println("foo"))

Comment: Happens to me as well, whenever i use REPL ill just `print("somthing")` then right click and `Clear All` and start working.. couldn't find any solution to this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

guys. In my case, the same exact problem sudly heppens. I found the solution just closeing the Android Studio and remove the .glade folder. After that, I re load my project. REPL with Kotlin Works perfect.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KbmGH.png)

Comment: Thanks - can confirm it works - seems to be enough to delete ~/.gradle/caches/

Answer (score 9):

The same exact problem happens to me. fortunately, this error goes away just by **right-clicking** then press **Clear All**.

Comment: Awesome solution! Thanks